# change a variable inside a list few times by using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Idk why this simple code is not working:

```
from keyboard import is_pressed
x, y, z = 10, 10, 10
m = 0.5

l = [x, y, z]
while z > 0:
    for c in l:
        if c > 0:
            c -= m
    print(l)
    if is_pressed('esc'):
        break
```

The goal is to continue the loop while every frame the variables in the list should get lower, but for some reason it stops getting lower after the first frame so it just keeps printing the same thing forever:

```
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
9.5
```

someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: stated simply: nowhere do you modify your list, or any of the objects in your list.

Comment: but it works at the first frame

Comment: You should add `print(list)` as the last line of your program.

Comment: @TheGreenLightning444 no, it doesn't work for any of them. You are simply printing the result of the operation `c -= m`, which again, stated simply, *does not modify your list or any of the objects in your list*. It creates *a new `int` object*, and assigns it to the variable `c`.

Comment: yeah ill fix it but it doesn't change it still will have the same problem

Comment: so there's no way to change it?

Comment: So, to give you a further hint, you either have to mutate the value in the list or mutate the list. But `int` objects are **immutable**, you cannot mutate them. So that leaves you with one option...

Comment: Yes, but you have to assign the new value back to the list.

Comment: For more information see the glossary entry for [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-immutable) and [mutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mutable).

Comment: Note that `z` is never changed, even if you mutate the list, so this will be infinite loop. And don't use `list` as name

Comment: Also: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)